# button click using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an asp.net button on a page without masterpage like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="target" runat="server" Text="Animate Me" >
</asp:Button>
```

and I am calling this:

```
var panel = $('#<%= target.ClientID %>');
panel.click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("value")); 
});
```

but no alert is shown. I even tried this:

```
$('#target').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("value")); 
});
```

but It didnt work.

Please suggest me how to click the button and what is issue in above code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Following code worked for me

```
 var panel = $('#<%= target.ClientID %>');
 eval(panel.trigger('click'));
```

and asp.net button looks like this.

```
 <asp:Button ID="target" runat="server" Text="Animate Me" 
     OnClientClick="alert('button clicked');return false;" > </asp:Button>
```

hope it will help someone sometime :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your code inside `$(document).ready()` Make sure it's wrapped

An example would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#target').click(function(){ 
     alert($(this).val());  //use .val() if you're getting the value
   });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how ASP.NET handles it, but have a look at your HTML. Depending on what type of button is created, you might have to change the code. Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/PUpnr/

Comment: Hi JohnP: I just checked and generated html looks like this :  <input type="submit" name="target" value="Animate Me" onclick="return false;" id="target" />

Comment: Ok, like user Yads mentions, you need to remove that onclick for this to work. And use .val() to get the value

Comment: @JohnP, I dont have onclick in button markup. I only have onclientClick

Comment: I'm talking about `onclick="return false;"` in the HTML markup that you posted. Not sure how ASP works, but you need to remove that. Unless there is an ASP specific way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because an asp server button creates an inline `onclick` handler that calls the `doPostBack` function. This function is run and submits the form to the server. This happens before your handler is run. I would suggest using an html input button (non server), alternatively you can use the `OnClientClick` attribute if you also need server side click handling.

Comment: actually, I am using JQUery QUnit and I need to perform a click of button from QUnit test and then see what is effect after click. I can't use onclientclick

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, if this is just for a test, you can remove the onclick attribute using jQuery.

Comment: I can't sue it because I need to test it against server side button click

Comment: @Dotnetsparrow, the effect after the click will be a call to doPostBack. So do you want to attach a handler or do you want to test what happens when you click the button?

Comment: In test I need to first create event handler and then test the effect

Comment: @Yads: BTW my test looks like this   asyncTest('Animation onClick', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    expect(1);
                    var panel = $('#<%= target.ClientID %>');                 
                    $('#target').click(function () { alert($(this).val()); });                  
                    var actual = panel.css('background-color');
                    equals(actual, 'blue', 'Calling onClick');
                    start();                  
                }, 100);
            });